# Where should I define location of flutter sdk?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

This is the error I get:

Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.

And this is what my file looks like currently, I'm not sure where to add this line because I'm completely new to flutter

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply from: project(':flutter_config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using android studio / intelij:

Go to Settings > Languages & frameworks > flutter > flutter SDK path

[image]

Then go to `android/local.properties` and add path again (create this file if it doesn't exist, if you are on windows, you should escape `\` like this: `C:\\Users\\user\\flutter`):

[image]

Comment: I did that but I get the same error unfortunately. This is the path I put:
C:\Users\my_username\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\flutter

Comment: Does it show the version of flutter under it after you put the path?

Comment: I edit the answer to include the `local.properties` file.